# AlertDialog.Builder wont show in current fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-alertdialog

so i have this sidemenu item called appinfo in TemplateHome activity (the default fragment is HomeFragment) that will show the app version inside AlertDialog.Builder

i was able to show the alertdialog just fine, but everytime i click on appinfo menu, the app will always go to HomeFragment/TemplateHome activity

Now does anyone know how to show the alertdialog in the current fragment?

this is my menu code

```
public void switchhomefragment(MenuItem item) {
        fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sidemenu_profil:
                fragmentClass = ProfileFragment.class;
                currentfragment = "home";
                break;
            case R.id.sidemenu_pencarian:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                currentfragment = "home";
                break;
            case R.id.sidemenu_pendaftaran:
                fragmentClass = PendaftaranFragment.class;
                currentfragment = "home";
                break;
            case R.id.sidemenu_fav:
                break;
            case R.id.sidemenu_tentang:
                fragmentClass = TentangFragment.class;
                currentfragment = "home";
                break;
            case R.id.sidemenu_info:
                infoaplikasi();
                break;
            case R.id.action_home:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                currentfragment = "home";
                break;
            case R.id.sidemenu_signout:
                editor.remove("sessioniduser");
                editor.commit();
                methodUmum.tologin(this);
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                currentfragment = "home";
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("templatehome", "isi error : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.flContent, fragment, currentfragment).commit();
        item.setChecked(true);
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
```

this is where i call the switchhomefragment code

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switchhomefragment(item);
        return true;
    }
```

and this is the AlertDialog.Builder code

```
public void infoaplikasi() {
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TemplateHome.this);
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_aplikasi, null);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setNegativeButton("TUTUP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

and this is my info_aplikasi xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ukr16"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/ukr16"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/ukr16">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ukr8"
        android:text="App Version"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="version 2.1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any advice is helpfull, Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welp my bad, i just realized that i set the fragmentclass value with HomeFragment.class. thats why the alert keep going to HomeFragment all this time

Answer (score 1):

In my app, your dialog pops up, so code inside `infoaplikasi` method is ok. I think that problem is `switchhomefragment` method. Do you call it properly? Put a breakpoint on                `infoaplikasi();` in that method and see if it is executed. Also, show us `R.layout.info_aplikasi`, maybe here's a problem.

PS. Use proper names conventions in your code. Code conventions for java can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: hm, i dont think there are problems with method switchhomefragment. What make me confused is the "getLayoutInflater()" in infoaplikasi method, is it the one causing alertdialog to show only in TemplateHome activity? also i already updated my code :)

Comment: Your fragment is in Activity, so if you call dialog from Activity it will be visible to the user anyway. In your layout, change `LinearLayout` ` android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `wrap_content` and change all `fill_parent` to `match_parent`. `fill_parent` is deprecated. Did you try to add a simple button on your activity's layout and call infoaplikasi from there?

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your help :) , but i already solved this problem. Have a nice day sir!

Comment: No problem :) Can you upvote my answer? I need 4 reputation points to be able to write comments ;)